# Finding similarities in text, and more specifically answers to the text? - PHP

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I have a unique situation in the sense that what I am asking is for my own convenience rather than the end user of my application.

I am attempting to create an application that tests peoples' IQ scores (I know they are irrelevant and not much use to anyone), nothing too serious, just a project of mine to keep me busy in between assignments.

I am writing it locally in WAMP with PHP. I have found that there are a lot of available IQ questions and answers on the internet that I can use for my project. I have also noticed that there are a lot of the same questions but they are worded slightly differently.

Is there any third party PHP library that I can utilize in order to stop me from including "two" of the same questions in my application?

Some examples of questions that are the "same" but programatically are considered different;

```
The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them, at the most, how many may be greater than zero?

The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them how many may be greater than zero?

The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them how many may be greater than zero, at the most?
```

Obviously you can see that PHP itself using operators cannot accomplish this and myself trying to differentiate between the similarities in the questions is far greater than my programming skill.

I have looked into plagiarism software but have not found any open source PHP projects.

Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks

** EDIT **

One idea I had was before inserting a question use `explode` at every space, and then in the resulting array match it against other questions that have also had the same function applied. The more matches the more equal the questions are?

I am a newcomer to PHP does this sound feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **acfrancis** has already answered: it doesn't get much simpler than using the built in `levenshtein` function.

However, to answer your final question: yes, doing it the way that you suggest is feasible and not too difficult.

### Code

```
function checkQuestions($para1, $para2){
    $arr1 = array_unique(array_filter(explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', strtolower($para1)))));
    $arr2 = array_unique(array_filter(explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', strtolower($para2)))));

    $intersect = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);


    $p1     = count($arr1);            //Number of words in para1
    $p2     = count($arr2);            //Number of words in para2
    $in     = count($intersect);       //Number of words in intersect
    $lowest = ($p1 < $p2) ? $p1 : $p2; //Which is smaller p1 or p2?


    return array(
        'Average'  => number_format((100 / (($p1+$p2) / 2)) * $in, 2), //Percentage the same compared to average length of questions
        'Smallest' => number_format((100 / $lowest) * $in, 2)          //Percentage the same compared to shortest question
        );
}
```

### Explanation

1. We define a function that accepts two arguments (the arguments being the questions that we're comparing).
2. We filter the input and convert to an array

   - Make the input lower case `strtolower`
   - Filter out non-alpha-numeric characters `preg_replace`
3. We explode the filtered string on spaces
4. We filter the created array

   - Remove *blanks* `array_filter`
   - Remove duplicates `array_unique`
5. Repeat `2-4` for the second question
6. Find matching words in both arrays and move to new array `$intersect`
7. Count number of words in each of the three arrays `$p1`, `$p2`, and `$in`
8. Calculate percentage similarity and return

You'd then need to set a threshold for how similar the questions had to be before being deemed *the same* e.g. `80%`.

**N.B.**

- The function returns an array of two values. The first comparing the length to the average of the two input questions the second only to the shortest. You could modify it returns a single value.
- I used `number_format` for the percentages... But you'd be fine with returning `int` *probably*

## Examples

#### Example 1

```
$question1 = 'The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them, at the most, how many may be greater than zero?';
$question2 = 'The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them how many may be greater than zero?';

if(checkQuestions($question1, $question2)['Average'] >= 80){
    echo "Questions are the same...";
}
else{
    echo "Questions are not the same...";
}

//Output: Questions are the same...
```

#### Example 2

```
$para1 = 'The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them, at the most, how many may be greater than zero?';
$para2 = 'The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them how many may be greater than zero?';
$para3 = 'The average of 20 numbers is zero. Of them how many may be greater than zero, at the most?';

var_dump(checkQuestions($para1, $para2));
var_dump(checkQuestions($para1, $para3));
var_dump(checkQuestions($para2, $para3));

/**

Output:

array(2) {
  ["Average"]=>
  string(5) "93.33"
  ["Smallest"]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
}
array(2) {
  ["Average"]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
  ["Smallest"]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
}
array(2) {
  ["Average"]=>
  string(5) "93.33"
  ["Smallest"]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
}

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Levenstein Distance algorithm:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

I've used it (in C#, not PHP) for a similar problem and it works quite well. The trick I found is to divide the Levenstein Distance by the length of the first sentence (in characters). That will give you a rough percentage of change required to convert question 1 into question 2 (for example).

In my experience, if you get anything less than 50-60% (i.e., less than 0.5 or 0.6), the sentences are the same. It might seem high but notice that 100% isn't the maximum. For example, to convert the string `"z"` into `"abcdefghi"` requires around 10 character changes (that's the Levenstein Distance: remove `z` then add `abcdefghi`) or a change of 1,000% as per the calculation above. With big enough changes, you can convert any random string into any other random string.